# HTML Form using mail function not receiving mail in my gmail account on hosted server

Tags: php, html, email, gmail

I have created a simple HTML form I used php mail function to mail the form in my Gmail account but I am not receiving any mail after submitting that form. I am not using any localhost it's live on Internet. Need some solution guys

```
index.html   <----- Contact Form ------>

<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="one" class="form-input" placeholder="Name">
                        <input type="text" name="phone" id="two" class="form-input" placeholder="Mobile Number">
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="three" class="form-input" placeholder="Email Address">

                        <select class="form-input" id="four" name="place">
                            <option value="volvo">Centers</option>
                          <option value="volvo">India</option>
                          <option value="saab">USA</option>
                          <option value="mercedes">Singapore</option>
                          <option value="audi">China</option>
                          <option value="audi">Pakistan</option>
                        </select>
                        
                        <div class="submit">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit-btn">
                        </div>

                    </form>

mail.php  <------ mail function written here ------>

<?PHP
$sender = $_POST['email'];
$recipient = 'jhon@gmail.com';

$subject = "php mail test";
$message = "php test message";
$headers = 'From:' . $sender;

if (mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
    echo "Message accepted";
}
else
{
    echo "Error: Message not accepted";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gmail to sent the mail click on this link https://myaccount.google.com/intro/security?pli=1#connectedapps and go to Allow less secure app (After Login to your gmail.com) change it into yes..

Answer (score 0):

Some of the hosting providers do not have the mail() enabled. So, before you send the mail, you need to be sure whether the mail() in enabled or not. Use the following to test that.

```
<?php
if ( function_exists( 'mail' ) )
{
    echo 'mail() is available';
}
else
{
    echo 'mail() has been disabled';
}
?>
```

And if the mail function is enabled and still not sending the mail, try using

```
@mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers)
```

It forces to use the mail() in the server.